# Determine variance contribution of each player in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, pca, covariance

after looking at a multitude of methods and posts, it is not yet clear to me how to solve this issue which seems intuitively simple.
I have the following dataset with the scores of 5 players. Its sample variance is 2.98108.

```
PLAYER  |   SCORE
-------------------
Bernard |   22.66
Bernard |   27.365
Bernard |   22.814
Anton   |   25.012
Anton   |   23.676
Anton   |   23.954
Carine  |   24.722
Carine  |   24.026
Carine  |   24.335
Carine  |   24.05
Bernard |   23.925
Bernard |   24.355
Bernard |   26.699
Carine  |   27.999
David   |   28.701
David   |   22.57
David   |   22.365
David   |   25.49
David   |   26.757
David   |   23.878
David   |   24.609
David   |   22.803
Anton   |   25.227
Anton   |   25.348
Carine  |   27.523
Carine  |   28.38
Carine  |   28.628
Bernard |   26.651
Bernard |   25.377
Anton   |   27.767
Anton   |   24.81
Anton   |   24.835
Eloy    |   26.672
Eloy    |   25.683
Eloy    |   26.657
Eloy    |   24.463
Eloy    |   25.808
Eloy    |   25.414
Eloy    |   26.044
Eloy    |   25.619
```

I would like to determine to which extend each of the players contributed to the variance of the whole.

```
Anton   |   Bernard |   Carine  |   David   |   Eloy
------------------------------------------------------                              
25.227  |   26.651  |   24.722  |   28.701  |   26.672
25.348  |   25.377  |   24.026  |   22.57   |   25.683
27.767  |   22.66   |   24.335  |   22.365  |   26.657
24.81   |   27.365  |   24.05   |   25.49   |   24.463
24.835  |   22.814  |   27.523  |   26.757  |   25.808
25.012  |   23.925  |   28.38   |   23.878  |   25.414
23.676  |   24.355  |   28.628  |   24.609  |   26.044
23.954  |   26.699  |   27.999  |   22.803  |   25.619
```

Note that I do not have any target variable: I am not fitting the players scores to a dependant variable. This makes it (to me) difficult to use methods like the shapley value, sklearn.feature_selection.chi2, or feature_importances_ where fit and fit_transform require a target variable.

Scikit’s PCA gives the following matrices:

components_:

```
-0.21261656 |   0.56000412  |   -0.19875582 |   0.77420244  |   -0.04791964
-0.31918083 |   -0.29286871 |   0.83464075  |   0.33964441  |   0.01918345
0.50226936  |   -0.55051268 |   -0.21507693 |   0.50440938  |   0.37943954
0.08884174  |   -0.33440461 |   -0.13381735 |   0.17548621  |   -0.9119091
0.76990287  |   0.4309671   |   0.44688451  |   0.00529465  |   -0.14759107
```

explained_variance_ratio_:

```
0.43725481  |   0.38896865  |   0.14361466  |   0.01989021  |   0.01027166
```

I would like to have a result table like:

```
Anton       |   Bernard     |   Carine     |    David       |   Eloy
-------------------------------------------------------------------------                           
0.20195141  |   0.18162131  |   0.30601668  |   0.15273025  |   0.15768035
```

telling me that Carine was the biggest contributor with 30% of the total variance and so on for the remaining players.

Can I use those matrices (components and explained_variance_ratio) to infer the total contribution of each player to the total variance? If yes, how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each player has exactly 8 samples of data, sum the square errors from the (overall) mean for all the samples and sum these errors first by player (8 samples each, achieving 5 numbers) and sum these 5 numbers for an overall sum. Every of the 5 numbers, divided by this total, will give you the desired value.

Comment: Thanks! So I should measure the dispersion of each player’s score from the mean of the group, of course.
So each player’s total contribution equal the found percentage times the variance of the group?
One more question: in the case of missing values, should I replace them with the mean of the group instead of the mean of the player?

Comment: Actually in case of missing data, if you fill it with the mean, this would impact on individual contribution to the variance. It would obviously decrease it for that player. It would not work. You may attempt a weighted sum (for the remaining data for that player and for other players' data). In such case it doesn't make sense to measure individual contribution when there is missing data: it means you can't measure it.

Comment: Is it required that all players have the same amount of observations? From a couple of simulations, it seems that when one player played 5 times instead of 8, his contribution to the group variance is still measured.

Comment: Yes it would carry a different weight. You could divide the overall sum by the number of observations and the player aggregate sum by the number of that player's observations, then according to total observations rescale in weighted manner. Not even sure it will work, give it a go.

Comment: I will give it a go. Thanks again for your insights!